# Android build in unity 2022.3

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, build.gradle, java-11

I'm trying to build an android app in unity 2022.3.1f

Unity have make a lot of improvements in android build with upgrade gradle and ndk and jdk

And when I'm trying to build in unity 2022

It give me an error in sdkmanger.bat

That "java tools option" isn't in jdk11

And it have been removed

And unity 2022 is using Jdk 11 and sdkmanger.bat need jdk8 to run and build my app in unity because jdk8 has the "java tool option"

And the only solution to build in unity 2022 if I want is to export project to android studie and build it from there and it is not an good idea to do

So can any one help me with that problem

I tried to replace android commend tools and change sdk and jdk And nothing works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to download Android SDK 33. At least that fixed it.This is how did it.

```
1- Edit > Project Settings > Player > Minimum API Level > Android 13 (API version 33).
2- File > Build And Run

The build and run will ask you to download SDK 33 (if not already), you just have to confirm.
```

Or

```
you getting solution from https://youtu.be/BpoB9WYrluk?si=Uc2G2k_LqI9oiRTa
```